# how to control the xml output during serialization

Tags: c#

if any property is blank or null then for that property xml tag is generated like `</Attention>`
but i want to generate it like `<Attention></Attention>`. so implement IXmlSerializable interface and from the WriteXml() method i tried to change the xml tag when the value is null or empty but still not getting right output. so please tell me what i need to do to generate the xml tag like `<Attention></Attention>` this if my Attention property is null or empty. basically i want customization of xml output. please guide me.

Comment: There's a difference between blank and null (for strings, in particular); and `null` values are generally **omitted** rather than included as empty. However the self-closed `<Attention/>` is perfectly fine xml for an empty element. If you have a separate parser that complains about that, then the parser is at fault, not the serializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to implement this once because the server that was receiving my Xml would crash on such tags. I wouldn't go implement your own serialization code, but instead do some post-processing (`Regex.Replace()`) after serialization, keeping the rest of your code clean.